# How do I edit layout.css in child theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, parent-child

I am working inside child theme. 
My `style.css` file in the child theme works fine but my `layout.css` file does not work in the child theme.

Directory structure for `layout.css` in parent theme is `mytheme/css/layout.css`

I've kept the same directory structure in child theme which is `mychildtheme/css/layout.css`

But when I write a code in child `layout.css`,  it doesn't work.

Browser picks the code from parent theme (`layout.css`)

Kindly let me know what must I do so that my `layout.css` in child theme will work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stylesheet is different than a regular theme php file. With such a php file, it's enough to create a file with the same name in your theme, and WP will know to use it. With css, however, it's not enough to create a file with the same name. You have to explicitly include it into the pages you want.

The best way to do that would be using the [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) function in your child theme's `function.php` file. Here is the way to do it given the directory structure you described:

```
 <?php wp_enqueue_style( 'child-theme-layout', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/layout.css' ); ?>
```

Comment: hi lea cohen.  i will write that function in my child function.php.

Comment: DO you kindly explain "You have to explicitly include it into the pages you want."

Comment: As i am using one style.css in my child theme. where i will include it. Thanks

Comment: Hi @MC3 - the to include it is using the code given in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the layout.css file in your child theme.
For more detailed information, you can have a look here :

> > > http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to make sure that your child theme's style.css is loaded after the parent theme's layout.css. Then you can easily override the small things you need in the usual manner via style.css

Here is some code that works for WooThemes products, which ensures that your child theme css is always loaded after the parent child's layout.css

It belongs in the child theme's **functions.php**

```
function use_parent_theme_stylesheet() {
    // Use the parent theme's stylesheet
    return get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css';
}

function my_theme_styles() {
    $themeVersion = wp_get_theme()->get('Version');

    // Enqueue our style.css with our own version
    wp_enqueue_style('child-theme-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('woo-layout'), $themeVersion);
}

// Filter get_stylesheet_uri() to return the parent theme's stylesheet 
add_filter('stylesheet_uri', 'use_parent_theme_stylesheet');

// Enqueue this theme's scripts and styles (after parent theme)
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_styles', 20);
```